# How do we the halt the execution flow, till we get the response from a callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, shippo

I'm passing an array to `async.each()`, where the execution will pass through the `if` condition, it adds the items to the array when the condition is satisfied while entering into the `else` statement, the execution will not wait for the shippo response. It moves into the next line and sends the response to the server.

I noticed that we are getting the response from `shippo` a few seconds later, so I placed a `setTimeout()` function after the completion of `else` block, but even in my console the message `'c'` will print last. I'm very much confused with the callbacks, how they will work. Is there any other way to the halt the execution flow till we get the response from `shippo`.

```
var async = require('async');
import each from 'async/each';

async.each(trackingnumbers, function (value, callback) {
            value['TrackingNo'] = parseInt(value['TrackingNo']);
            value['Provider'] = value['Provider'].toLowerCase();

    if (value['Provider'] == "domestic") {
                items.push({ 'TrackingNo': value['TrackingNo'], 'Provider': value['Provider'], 'Status': 'Completed' });
                console.log('a');
             }
            else {
              console.log('b');
                shippo.track.get_status(value['Provider'], value['TrackingNo']).then(function (status) {
                  console.log('c');
                    items.push({ 'TrackingNo': value['TrackingNo'], 'Provider': value['Provider'], 'Status': status.tracking_status });
                }, functionconsole.log('d'); (err) {
                    console.log("There was an error retrieving tracking information: %s",+ err);
                    callback('There was an error retrieving tracking information:');
                    // 
                });
              console.log('d');  
   e  }
   console.log('e');
            setTimeout(function(){
                callback();
            },3000);
}, function (err) {
      if (err) {
          console.log('error occured ' + '|' + err);
      }
      else {
          console.log(items);
          res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          res.send(items).status('200');
      }
 });
```

[Here is my output along with the shippo response after we placed an timeout function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkqIu.png)

Comment: The idea with callbacks is that you just don't do anything after you've made the call, and then execute the callback function when the call is complete.  To halt execution you simply don't have any code after the call.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest reviewing the documentation for the [`async`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) library regarding [`AsyncFunction()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/global.html). It looks like you are supposed to call the callback whether you have successfully completed your request *or* an Error has occurred.

Since the Shippo library is using `'when'` for handling promise-like chaining (at the time of this writing, I have an open [PR on GitHub](https://github.com/goshippo/shippo-node-client/pull/39) to deprecate that to more normal promise chaining).

As a result of using `'when'`, it means that to catch errors you would pass `.then()` two functions, one for a success path and another for handling errors. It would work kind of like this:

```
shippo.track.get_status('usps', '1122334455667788')
      .then(function (results){
         // do stuff with your successful function call
      }, function (error) {
         // do stuff with the error you just received
      });
```

The reason that `console.log('c')` is printing out last, is because it won't execute that line until the original promise has resolved for retrieving the tracking status from Shippo.

Also, by calling the `callback()` in a `setTimeout()` function, you're only delaying each iteration from resolving by 3 seconds, but don't necessarily guarantee that your call on the `shippo` function was successful or not.

You should be calling the `callback()` function *inside* of each of the functions passed into `then()`. So that once you have received your results, you can resolve the instance of the function called by `async.each()`. By handling the `callback()` inside of the those functions, you can correctly handle successes and errors.